# hiding address/ url bar on html viewer

Tags: abap

Is there a way that I can hide the address/url bar? I am using cl_gui_html_viewer. 
best regards.

These are the declared types,

```
DATA: html_control TYPE REF TO cl_gui_html_viewer,
      my_container TYPE REF TO cl_gui_custom_container.
```

Comment: CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER doesn't display the address bar. You probably did something special. Can you show your screen?

Comment: [LINK](https://imgur.com/a/J0jQjl9) This is the link. its the small bar on the top.

Comment: It's a screen field which is part of the dynpro, it does not belong to CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER.

Comment: yes you're right, i got the code from the demo program of html_viewer in sap. thank you very much.
 Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER doesn't display the address bar.

It's a screen field which is part of the dynpro, it does not belong to CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER.